# Manually changing a group of bytes in an unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm working with C and I'm trying to figure out how to change a set of bits in a 32-bit unsigned integer.

For example, if I have

```
int a = 17212403u;
```

In binary, that becomes `1000001101010001111110011`. Now, supposing I labeled these bits, which are arranged in little-endian format, such that the bit utmost right represents the ones, the second to the right is the twos, and so on, how can I manually change a group of bits?

**For example, suppose I wanted to change the bits such that the 11th bit to the 15th bit has the decimal value of 17. How would this be possible?**

I was thinking of getting that range by doing as such:

```
unsigned int range = (a << (sizeof(a) * 8) - 14) >> (28)
```

But I'm not sure where to go on from now.

Comment: `int a = 17212403u;` is  assigning an _unsigned_ value to a _signed_ variable.  Certainly doing shifts is a lot less problematic  sticking with unsigned variables and constants.  Reccomend `unsigned a = 17212403u;`

Comment: 17 is 10001B.  bit 11-15 is 5 bits too ,so it will fit.  First, force those bits low by ANDing with a mask of  NOT (11111B<<11).  Then shift the 17 up 11 places, and OR it in.

Comment: Little- and big-endian don't apply to bit "order". Since bits are not individually addressable, there is no concept of a lower address to appeal to. But it's worth noting that little-endian *byte* ordering means that the "leftmost" byte (the one with the lowest address) is the low-order end, which is the reverse of what you seem to think "little-endian" means.

Comment: To change a contiguous field in a word, first (a) set those bits to zero, then (b) use bitwise-OR to set them to the new value.  (a) can be achieved by creating a mask that is 0 where the field is and 1 elsewhere, then using bitwise-AND.  (b) can be achieved by left-shifting the new value to the proper position, then using bitwise-OR.  It's also a good idea to use unsigned integers to avoid overflow issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will (1) first have to clear the bits 11..15, and (2) then to set the bits according to the value you want to set. To achieve (1), create a "mask" that has all bits set to `1` except the ones that you want to clear; use then `a & bitMask` to set the bits to `0`. Then, use `| myValue` to set the bits to the value wanted.
Use the bit shift operator `<<` to place the mask and the value at the right positions:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Let's assume a range of 5 bits
    unsigned int bitRange = 0x1Fu;  // is ...00000000011111

    // Let's assume to position the range from bit 11 onwards (i.e. move 10 left):
    bitRange = bitRange << 10;             // something like 000000111110000000000
    unsigned int bitMask = ~bitRange;      // something like 111111000001111111111
    unsigned int valueToSet = (17u << 10); // corresponds to 000000101110000000000

    unsigned int a = (17212403u & bitMask) | valueToSet;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the long version to explain what's going on. In brief, you could also write:

```
unsigned int a = (17212403u & ~(0x1Fu << 10)) | (17u << 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The 11th to 15th bit is 5 bits, assuming you meant including the 15th bit. 5 bits is the hex value: `0x1f`

Then you shift these 5 bits 11 position to the left:`0x1f << 11`

Now we have a mask for the bits 11 through 15 that we want to clear in the original variable, which - we do that by inverting the mask, bitwise and the variable with the inverted mask: `a & ~(0x1f << 11)`

Next is shifting the value 17 up to the 11th bit: `17 << 11`

Then we bitwise or that into the 5 bits we have cleared:

```
unsigned int b = (a & ~(0x1f << 11)) | (17 << 11)
```

Comment: I recommend to use unsigned constants like `0x1fu, 17u`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using bit fields. This allows you to name and access sub-sections of the integer as though they were integer members of a struct.

For info on C bitfields see: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm

Below is code to do what you want, using bitfields.  The "middle5" member of the struct holds bits 11-15.  The "lower11" member is a filler for the lower 11 bits, so that the "middle5" member will be in the right place.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showBits(unsigned int w)
{
  unsigned int bit = 1<<31;
  while (bit > 0) 
  {
    printf("%d", ((bit & w) != 0)? 1 : 0);
    bit >>= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  struct aBitfield {
      unsigned int lower11: 11;
      unsigned int middle5:  5;
      unsigned int upper16: 16;
  };

  union uintBits {
    unsigned int     whole;
    struct aBitfield parts;
  };

  union uintBits b;

  b.whole = 17212403u;

  printf("Before:\n");
  showBits(b.whole);

  b.parts.middle5 = 17;

  printf("After:\n"); 
  showBits(b.whole);    
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Before:
00000001000001101010001111110011
After:
00000001000001101000101111110011
```

Of course, you would want to use more meaningful naming for the various fields.

Be careful though, bitfields may be implemented differently on different platforms - so it may not be completely portable.